# Load Balancer Route 53 SSL Connection Refused?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-route53

As of now the propagation is done already

How did I checked it?

1. ping `<public-ip-of-instance>`
2. I tried to check my domain using `HTTP` Request and it works fine. The site loading fine on port 80

Things I've checked

1. Security Group - As of now my load balancer uses the security group of my instance.

these are the following:

`80, 443, 22`

2. And pointed my ELB to `<domain.com>` & `<www.domain.com>` you can check it on the lower part of the image  and upper part.

[image]

3. As you can notice there's a lot of A Record thsoe are the subdomains and emails. that needs to be kept with their IP Addresses.

Subdomain are working fine right now. But the domain doesn't work on port 443 and I don't know why.

PS: in my dns provider I changed the `nameserver` given from the created zone and `@ A Record` pointed to my instance public ip.

Is there anything I missed?

**UPDATE**

[image]

```
  `ns-xxx.awsdns-47.co.uk. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7xxx0 900 1xxxxx00 8xxxx0`
```

Comment: If you do an SOA lookup does it point to Route53? 

I always use https://whatsmydns.net to check DNS propagation

Comment: I update post, Can u please check it

Comment: Did you check the health tab on your load balancer configuration? Are all the targets in rotation?

Comment: It doesn't sound like a DNS problem if port 80 works, but from a unix machine try running dig +trace @4.2.2.2 www.yourdomain.com to double check the ip address and that all the NS's A records can be found. The reason I was asking about your targets in your ELB is because your ELB can have a really unexpected ip addresses, and will change ips every time you reconfigure it.